# Ansible playbook reference a git role which should run on localhost but it doesn't

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I need to be able to use the ansible git module to `git pull` on ansible controller from the respective branch based on the target branch of commit / merge. I put the ansible git in a role and reference that role in every playbook as the first thing to do. This git role runs on `localhost`.

I have the following inventory:

```
PreProd:
  hosts:
    myhost.mydomain.com:

local:
  hosts:
    localhost:
```

and the playbook:

```
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - "../group_vars/{{ ENV }}/{{ ENV }}.yml"

  tasks:
    - name: Print variables
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ENV }} {{ var_username }}:{{ var_password }} branch: {{ var_branch }}"

  roles:
  - git

- name: Deploy My Application
  hosts: "{{ ENV }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "branch: {{ var_branch }}"
```

And I have the following structure in `group_vars`:

```
group_vars\
   all\all.yml
   PreProd\PreProd.yml
```

I have the `var_branch` variable defined in all groups in `group_vars` but NOT in `group_vars\all\all.yml` because this variable is specific to the environment.

When I run the playbook, it tries to make connection even though it shows `localhost`:

```
$  ansible-playbook -i preprod-servers.yml playbooks/test.yml -e ENV=PreProd

PLAY [local] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [git : Get latest code from repository] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Kerberos auth failure for principal me@domain.com with pexpect: <redacted>k<redacted>i<redacted>n<redacted>i<redacted>t<redacted>:<redacted> <redacted>P<redacted>a<redacted>s<redacted>s<redacted>w<redacted>o<redacted>r<redacted>d<redacted> <redacted>i<redacted>n<redacted>c<redacted>o<redacted>r<redacted>r<redacted>e<redacted>c<redacted>t<redacted> <redacted>w<redacted>h<redacted>i<redacted>l<redacted>e<redacted> <redacted>g<redacted>e<redacted>t<redacted>t<redacted>i<redacted>n<redacted>g<redacted> <redacted>i<redacted>n<redacted>i<redacted>t<redacted>i<redacted>a<redacted>l<redacted> <redacted>c<redacted>r<redacted>e<redacted>d<redacted>e<redacted>n<redacted>t<redacted>i<redacted>a<redacted>l<redacted>s<redacted>", "unreachable": true}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: How about this: 'Password incorrect while getting initial credentials'

Answer (score 0):

Advice:

1. NEVER have multiple environments (such as PREPROD and LOCAL) in the
   same inventory.
2. Ansible will automatically assign the variables in the `group_vars` files to the hosts that are in those groups.  Do not use `vars_files` with `group_vars` files.
3. For the `local` group, or for `localhost`, set `connection: local`

Comment: I have updated my post with more details on the requirements.